# How to get a Unicode-supporting font for Windows 7 command-line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, fonts, i18n

I've pointed the command-line to the right codepage (`chcp 65001`), but there's a lot of Unicode 
characters that Consolas and Lucida Console can't show. Specifically, I want the printable IPA characters to show up. It's not important to fix multi-codepoint glyphs, although it would be nice.

How can I get such a font and install it for the command-line?

Below is an example of some characters that can't be rendered.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about that font, but read these two links to see if you can make them work.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingConsolasAsTheWindowsConsoleFont.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q247815

Comment: In order to add a font, it must be fixed-width, and I don't know any fixed-width fonts that supports the characters that I need.

Comment: What characters do you need? I have to go now, but I will look at your response when I get back.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking mainly for the [IPA extensions block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_Extensions_(Unicode_block)) (U+0250 to U+02AF).

Comment: @Tim Like you, I found that was hard to find. Too many of the sites had very poor search functions to weed out the one that are not fixed-width. Have you considered trying to make your own with this: C:\WINDOWS\system32\eudcedit.exe (link with a fixed-width font, and add your own codes)? Depending on how inmportant it is, you could also consider buying font-making software for under $100, or even contracting someone on the Internet to make it for you (even this looks cheap).

Comment: Thank you for looking. I'll probably write an HTML interface instead, and keep these suggestions for when I don't have a choice.

Comment: The registry-based solution mentioned in the microsoft link worked for me. Thank you!